# how to implement wms layer into android studio with the help of wms .jar file

Tags: java, android, geoserver, wms

I am working on java android application based on geoserver to open wms layer in my activity.

1. I tried https://github.com/shalperin/android-wms.git
   Here, I couldn't fix the tile layer on the exact desired latlong position.
2. I worked on Arcgis Android API too. But it doesn't seems helpful so far.

I need to put http://mmcnav.com:8084/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Tigri&styles=&bbox=77.2339248657227,28.5064010620117,77.2387619018555,28.514077&width=322&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers
this layer into android application.

Please let me know exact way to do it.

Comment: Forgive me for my English also I don't know whether this is a correct way to ask question here or should I ask question on https://gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: A WMS layer is just an image, what exactly have you done and what doesn't work?

Comment: I need to put wms layer of desired latlong in android app so that whole layer should look like an image